# EOF error using recv in python

Tags: python, sockets

I am doing this in my code,

```
HOST = '192.168.1.3'    
PORT = 50007              
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
query_details = {"page" : page, "query" : query, "type" : type}
s.send(str(query_details))
#data = eval(pickle.loads(s.recv(4096)))
data = s.recv(16384)
```

But I am continually getting EOF at the last line. The code I am sending with,

```
self.request.send(pickle.dumps(results))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: is the `s.send(str(query_details))` call correct?

Comment: Correct in what sense? It's syntactically correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`s.send` is **not** guaranteed to send every byte you give it; use `s.sendall` instead.

Similarly, `s.recv` is **not** guaranteed to receive every byte you ask -- in that case you need to know by other ways exactly how many bytes you need to receive (e.g., send first the length of the string you're sending, encoded with the `struct` module) and you're responsible for doing the looping yourself to that purpose.  There isn't and cannot be any `recvall` because stream sockets are **not** "self-delimiting" in any way -- they're just streams, broken up into totally arbitrary packets of sizes not semantically relevant.

You shouldn't ever get an `EOF` from the `recv` itself, though of course you can expect to get it in the line you've commented out, from the `pickle.loads` (because its argument may well be only a *part* of the bytes that the counterpart sent: as explained in the previous paragraph).